# How can I trigger a GitHub Action workflow via an HTTP request using the GitHub REST API?

Tags: rest, http, github, github-actions

I am currently having difficulty understanding how to effectively utilize `GitHub Actions`. I have been seeking information on whether it is possible to trigger a `GitHub Action` through an `HTTP` request using the GitHub REST API.

For example, I would like to trigger a GitHub Action from my laptop using `curl` commands, or even create a script or third-party application that will trigger the actions themselves.

While I have reviewed [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest), I have only found information on retrieving information and not on triggering pipelines.
Could you provide guidance on this topic or links to relevant documentation? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Configure your workflow as [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) and then you can run it with the [GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow?tool=cli) from the command line.

Comment: You can check the CURL and JS samples here in the REST API docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event.